# Convert a pandas object into float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I was trying to make a code that could read a excel file, found which line corresponds to the data I want and then save the last value of that line.

The code I'm using is:

```
import pandas as ap
import numpy as np

#Read the Excel file
excel = ap.read_excel(r'EXAMPLE')

#Columns and rows selections
tec_data = excel.iloc[0::, 0:6]

#creating a numpy array with the table
np_array = tec_data.to_numpy()

#Found the line that corresponds to the pretended simulation data
found_tec_line = np.argwhere((month==np_array[:,0]) & (hour==np_array[:,1]) & (azimuth==np_array[:,2]) & (elevation==np_array[:,3]) & (height==np_array[:,4]))

#Save TEC
tec = np_array[found_tec_line,5]
```

So, at this stage I have the tec that is a array([['27.8 * 10 * * 15']], dtype=object)
I just want to save the 27.89* 10* * 15 as float but I don't know how to do it.
I used the tec = tec.astype(float), but it says "could not convert string to float: '27.89 * 10* * 15'"

Note: there is no spaces between the numbers and the * on the code, I introduced the spaces here just because of the automatic bold

Comment: can you show in your example what you want the output to look like. is it in excel? or back in dataframe? it's not clear what you want from the asterisks either

Comment: I just want to get that specific value from the excel and to use it afterwards (as a float) on other scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

tec = np_array[found_tec_line,5]
tec=pd.eval(tec)
```

**OR**

Try via `Dataframe()` method and `apply()` method:

```
tec = np_array[found_tec_line,5]

tec=pd.Dataframe(tec).apply(pd.eval).values
```

Comment: Thank you!
I added a tec =tec.astype(float) after the eval(tec) and already does what I wanted, saves the value as float.